# Deleting files in a pattern dump-{date}.-id.zip

Tags: command-line

I have a lot of files named dump-{date}.-id.zip.
I want to delete all of them with Terminal. What is the best command for doing this, so that I dont delete other files?

**Output from ls:**

```
bin                             dump-2017-09-07_142947-001.zip  dump-2017-09-26_151153-299.zip  dump-2017-10-05_122928-259.zip  dump-2017-10-11_125713-417.zip  extras       lock         system
dependencies.txt                dump-2017-09-08_073237-110.zip  dump-2017-09-27_083219-519.zip  dump-2017-10-05_160511-816.zip  dump-2017-10-13_150436-991.zip  fabric       metatype
deploy                          dump-2017-09-08_094416-216.zip  dump-2017-09-28_151635-932.zip  dump-2017-10-06_150632-110.zip  dump-2017-10-16_151015-243.zip  instances    notices.txt
dump-2017-09-04_125758-087.zip  dump-2017-09-08_094416-217.zip  dump-2017-09-29_145916-799.zip  dump-2017-10-09_111104-348.zip  dump-2017-10-20_101757-247.zip  lib          patches
dump-2017-09-06_153340-166.zip  dump-2017-09-11_130229-627.zip  dump-2017-10-04_132909-041.zip  dump-2017-10-09_164517-364.zip  dump-2017-10-27_153125-344.zip  licenses     quickstarts
dump-2017-09-07_101627-120.zip  dump-2017-09-26_132217-849.zip  dump-2017-10-04_134400-669.zip  dump-2017-10-10_142601-467.zip  etc                             license.txt  readme.txt
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given the output, a simple `rm dump-*.zip` should be enough. No other files start with `dump-` and end with `.zip`.

If you feel pedantic:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -regextype egrep -type f -regex './dump-[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}_[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{3}\.zip' -delete
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to check first, you could use `find` to first show you what is going to be operated on, and then delete:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "dump-*.zip"
```

Check that the output only contains files you want to remove, then add the `-delete` switch to the command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "dump-*.zip" -delete
```